# Models in a list can't be predicted upon

Tags: r, list, prediction

Consider a list of models that can be created by:

```
fits = vector(mode="list",length=10)
for(i in 1:10)
{
  fits[[i]] = lm(nox~poly(dis,i),data=Boston)
}
```

Where, `Boston` dataset is used, that can be found in the `MASS` library.
Now, in order to make predictions:

```
dislim = range(Boston$dis) 
dis.grid = seq(from = dislim[1],to = dislim[2],by = 0.1)
```

This is done to give values of `dis` upon which `nox`'s values are predicted.
Now, in order to make predictions, we can do the following:

```
 predict(fits[[1]],list(dis = dis.grid))
```

But this results in an error:

```
Error: variable 'poly(dis, i)' was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but type "nmatrix.10" was supplied
In addition: Warning message:
In Z/rep(sqrt(norm2[-1L]), each = length(x)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

But, when I do the following:

```
lm.Boston = lm(nox~poly(dis,3),data=Boston)
lm.Boston.pred = predict(lm.Boston,list(dis = dis.grid))
```

It works fine. So, why can't I do that in the case of a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to specify a dynamic formula is to use `paste` and `as.formula`

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)

dislim <- range(Boston$dis) 
dis.grid <- seq(from = dislim[1],to = dislim[2],by = 0.1)

models <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
  form = as.formula(paste0("nox~", "poly(dis," , i, ")"))
  lm(form, data=Boston)
})
```

to predict

```
lapply(models, function(x){
  predict(x, list(dis = dis.grid))
})
```

EDIT: Another way to build the formula (as per MrFlick comment) is:

```
`lm(bquote(nox~poly(dis,.(i))), data=Boston)`

models1 <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
  lm(bquote(nox~poly(dis,.(i))), data=Boston)
})
```

Additionally (as per Nathan Werth comment) if the formulation:

```
models2 <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
    lm(nox~poly(dis,i),data=Boston)
})
```

is used, the `i` is being treated as a variable in the model and it is possible to exploit such behavior in the following way:

```
predict(models2[[1]], list(dis = dis.grid, i = 1)

library(purrr)
models <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
  form = as.formula(paste0("nox~", "poly(dis," , i, ")"))
  lm(form, data=Boston)
})

models1 <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
  lm(bquote(nox~poly(dis,.(i))), data=Boston)
})

models2 <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
  lm(nox~poly(dis,i),data=Boston)
})

missuse <- lapply(models, function(x){
  predict(x,list(dis = dis.grid))
})

MrFlick <- lapply(models1, function(x){
  predict(x,list(dis = dis.grid))
})

NathanWerth <- purrr::map2(models2, 1:10, function(x, y){
  predict(x,list(dis = dis.grid, i = y ))
})

purrr::pmap(list(missuse, MrFlick, NathanWerth), function(x, y, z) c(identical(x, y), identical(x, z)))
```

Comment: To expand on this, the problem with @mooncrater's code is the `i` in `poly(dis, i)` was being captured as a  variable in the model.  So it's possible to use each model like `predict(fits[[1]], list(dis = dis.grid, i = 1))`.  But that's not very useful.

Comment: You could also use `lm(bquote(nox~poly(dis,.(i))), data=Boston)` rather than `paste()` to build the formula.